# Script for Folder transfer from DEV server to TEST server

Tags: unix, ftp, tar

can you pls provide me the script which should like below

Transfer the tar zip directory from dev server to test server

Also it shoud check for chekcsum , junk charcter in the directories once transfered to test server .

and I am new to this unix so can you pls guide me

Thanks,
Mangala

Comment: This is not a script writing service. What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't a good question at all. Please have a look at the [how to ask help](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)!

You should have a look into SSH and rsync:

```
man rsync
```

There are examples as well.

If you've setup SSH correctly, you should be able to copy a directory via rsync for example by executing:

```
rsync -avz "/foo/bar" user@host.example.net:"/foo/bar"
```

If you want to delete extraneous files on the target host, add the `--delete` option as well.